# How to pass data from First ViewController directly to the Third View Controller using segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift4

I was able to perform the task of passing value from one view controller to another view controller. I had a textField and submit button in one view controller and in another I had a label, after I gave input to the textField, I was able to replace the label text with textField's text.

But now what I am trying is that when I click on submit button in first view controller , it should move to second view controller (performSegue) and at the same time it should pass the value to the third view controller..

But I am getting an error if I do that, is there a simple way to pass values from one view controller to third view controller where I can skip "n" number of view controllers which come in between the target and destination?

Here's an example:

> Suppose there are three viewControllers,  first viewController has a
>   textField and a submit button, second view Controller has a "NEXT"
>   button and third View Controller has a label.

When I enter the textField and click on submit , it should submit the textField.text to third  View Controller and should perform segue to second view controller,

now  when I am on second view controller it'll show NEXT button. After I click on next, it'll take me to third View controller where it'll show me the first View COntroller's textField's text in the label...

My question is, how to do that? I went through a lot of youtube videos of implementing segues but nobody talked about how to pass data from one view controller to another view controller by skipping some view controllers.

I hope you do understand my question.

Your time and help will be highly appreciated! 
Thank You

Comment: have you ever used instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "") method to transite from one controller to another controller it's alternative of segue

Comment: Never heard about it, I am sorry I am new. I'll do some digging and try to implement it but it would be nice if you give me some reference based on it.

Comment: i know you are new cuz i have alredy solved ur one or two problems :)

Comment: Even if there is another view controller in the chain, you can create another segue that will skip the middle view controller. See my image: https://imgur.com/a/pylDPPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign storybordID to your controller for ex here i have assigned "HomeVC" (it would be greate if you assign class name and storybordid same)

```
  let objthirdController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdControllerStoerybordID") as! thirdControllerclassname
  objthirdController.variable = self.variable
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objthirdController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are able to perform the task of passing value from one view controller to another view controller. 
Repeat the same when you are in next controller, till you reach your destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

> you should use Notification Observer Design Pattern but its better to pass it throw the view controller instead of passing directly to destination ViewController but here is the solution:

```
struct NotificationKeys {
    static let myKey = "myKey"
}

class SourceViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func yourButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: NotificationKeys.myKey)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)
    }
}
```

> you can pass with object too, its so simple with object too,
>   just search pass data with NotificationCenter in google if you don't understand the code ;)

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createObserver()
    }

    func createObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateLabel(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NotificationKeys.myKey), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func updateLabel(notification:NSNotification) {
        let isText = notification.name.rawValue == NotificationKeys.myKey
        let text = isText ? "\(isText)" : ""
        yourLabel?.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! Appreciate your efforts in explaining this to me!